# BIOS is run every time computer starts

Tags: boot, windows-10, ssd, bios

I have just replaced my dvd-rom with a SSD and installed windows on it. Everything seems to be ok but I noticed that every time I restart, open the laptop, it enters in BIOS mode and it starts only if I go to Save&Exit and select Save and Exit. I also noticed that in the Boot tab there are no boot options and there is no possibility of adding a new boot option.

Laptop model: Asus ROG G551JK

Boot menu: http://postimg.org/image/cgmisbn8n/

Comment: Your computer has probably UEFI firmware. CSM means legacy (BIOS) booting. What if you disable CSM? Also, is your Windows using UEFI? ([Look for a EFI system partition](http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/29504-bios-mode-see-if-windows-boot-uefi-legacy-mode.html).) If not, how about reinstalling Windows in UEFI mode (with CSM disabled)?

Comment: In Disk Management for the SSD I can see this: http://postimg.org/image/fmv0hzmnb/

Comment: Yep. That was it. I disabled CSM and everything is ok now. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Ok, I'll post that as an answer. :)

Answer (score 1):

Your computer has probably UEFI firmware. CSM (in your image) means legacy BIOS booting. Your best bet would be to disable CSM and, if Windows was in BIOS mode and now fails to boot, reinstall Windows with proper UEFI support.